# Be pleased vs Please be

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Do these two phrases mean the same?

1. Be pleased to listen to me!
2. Please listen to me!

You can find the first one here http://lucianofsamosata.info/wiki/doku.php?id=antisthenes_of_athens:xenophon_symposium_4

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they mean the same, but (1) is formal and old-fashioned. The passage it is taken from appears to be a translation made several hundred years ago. Another version would be "Listen to me, if you please" (meaning 'if it pleases you to do so'). Nowadays we normally just use 'Please'.